# Converting Rows into Columns in a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, rows

I have a 99x1 cell array and I would like to convert it into a 33x3 cell array for example.

I would like the first 3 rows of the 99x1 cell array to make up the first row in the 33x3 cell array and then the 3rd through 6th row in the 99x1 cell array to make up the second row in the 33x3 cell array.

I also need the data when being reshaped to go over column by column before it goes down. For example I would need:

1
2
3
4

to become

1, 2; 3, 4

not

1, 3; 2, 4

Help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is the cell structure important? or does each cell have the same # of row \ columns?  I first thought a simple `reshape(yourcell,33,3)` would work, but I think you maybe want something else...  a simple minimal example would clarify your question.

Comment: This worked, however i need the data when being reshaped to go over column by column before it goes down. For example I need:

Comment: @young_coder isn’t that exactly what the solution in my answer does?!

Comment: Perhaps your example is oversimplified, but why do you need your data to be in a cell array? It's much faster and simpler to use a normal array, if possible.

Comment: @Max yes my apologies your code works perfectly. I thought the .' was inside of the reshape function when I copied it to my code. My mistake, thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: @young_coder No worries. If my answer solved your problem, however, consider excepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `reshape`-function. Since `reshape(yourcell,[],3)` would first fill the first column and then the second and so on instead of row-wise, you will need to combine it with the transpose operator `.'`:

```
newcell=reshape(yourcell,3,[]).'
```

This way, you will first create a `3x33` cell using the `reshape` and then transform it into the desired `33x3` cell. The `[]` tells reshape to create as many columns as needed.